# String with spaces not accepted in a manual job variables setting

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

I developed a pipeline in GitLab CI/CD. The last job of my pipeline is a manual job, where I need to enter some information within the job form.

Here is an example:

[image]

My problem is when I enter a string like "the description of my key". After starting the job with this key/value, I can only recover "the" (which is the first word of my key).

I don't understand why I can't recover all my string.

Important thing: My job starts a .sh script

```bash
my job:
  script:
    - sh my_script.sh KEY=$key
  when: manual

   ...
```

In this script, I "echo" my variable key and I only get "the" instead of "the description of my key"

#### How did I use the key value in my_script.sh?

```bash
# /bin/sh

for var in "$@"; do
  eval "${var}"
done


# I only get key="the" instead of key="the description of my key"
```

Comment: if I enter a my value like "the_description_of_my_key", it works. But I don't want the '_'. characters.
The spaces are the source of the problem.

Comment: "cat" does not execute any script. it only shows the script. besides, if you run "export" in your script you will see the key you entered in full (with spaces)

Comment: Yep. In my code I execute it through ssh, that's the reason why I made a mistake copying it ^^'

I already exporting the variable like :

export KEY="$key" 
echo "$KEY"

But it doesn't work at all

Comment: you might have a buggy gitlab version. our company have version 13.9.3 (enterprise edition) and it's working with our version

Comment: Still not working for me for gitlab version -> 13.10.3 (enterprise edition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I used "declare" instead of "eval"

```sh
for var in "$@"; do
  declare "${var}"
done

# key="the description of my key"
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable **key** has been passed down to gitlab correctly, the problem is encountered when you try to pass this variable to the bash script.

```
- sh my_script.sh KEY=$key
```

In order to pass the full value to the bash script you need to quote it.

When the bash expands the variable it encounters spaces, which are treated as special delimeters . So in order to achieve what you want change the above line to this

```
- sh my_script.sh KEY="$key"
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: I'm gonna try it soon :) Thank for your answer

Comment: Hello @PicxyB, I was curious if the answer provided the required behavior, or it needs modification

Comment: Hello @TolisGerodimos, thank you for your help, the solution was to change "eval" to "declare" (bin/sh and not bin/bash)